# NestJS Swagger Module: can't get a "shared" package in a monorepo to be transpiled properly

Tags: nestjs, openapi, nestjs-swagger

I’m having a hard time figuring out how to make the `@nestjs/swagger` plugin works in a specific package of my monorepo.

**Context**: I have a nestjs application and multiple frontend applications on the same monorepo as well as a package to share types across the repo (especially DTOs). I want to generate a swagger for the nestjs API without the hassle of defining every route properties manually, which is why I’d like to make the most out of the this plugin and the openapi integration

**What’s working**
Within the current nestjs application, I’ve defined a dummy type and use it like so:

```
// geolocation.controller.ts

import { DummyType } from './definition/dummy-type.dto';

@Version('2')
  @Post('/')
  async getGeolocationV2(@Body() body: DummyType) {
    ...
  }
```

```
// definition/dummy-type.dto

export class DummyType {
  /**
   * dummy key
   */
  key: string;
}
```

In the `swagger.jon` file generated I do have a the DummyType properly annotated, here's the resulted in transpiled .js file

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.DummyType = void 0;
const openapi = require("@nestjs/swagger");
class DummyType {
    static _OPENAPI_METADATA_FACTORY() {
        return { key: { required: true, type: () => String, description: "dummy key" } };
    }
}
exports.DummyType = DummyType;
//# sourceMappingURL=dummy-type.dto.js.map
```

What's not working?
Now the problem is when I try to do that from the actual package that holds all my DTO in the monorepo.

In my nest js application

```
// geolocation.controller.ts

import { GeocodingRequestBody } from 'my-shared-package';

  /**
   * return geolocation coordinates based on a address
   */
  @Version('3')
  @Post('/')
  async getGeolocationV3(@Body() body: GeocodingRequestBody) {
    ...
  }
```

```
// my-shared-package/.../geolocation-request.dto.ts

export class GeocodingRequestBody {
  /**
   * dummy value
   */
  property_one: string;
}
```

Here's the transpiled JS file in that shared package

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.GeocodingRequestBody = void 0;
const openapi = require("@nestjs/swagger");
class GeocodingRequestBody {
}
exports.GeocodingRequestBody = GeocodingRequestBody;
//# sourceMappingURL=geolocation-request.dto.js.map
```

There is no `_OPENAPI_METADATA_FACTORY()` as I would expect

I’m transpiling this “shared-package” with nest CLI  (as per, https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/580)

```bash
barrelsby --delete -c barrelsby.json && nest build --path tsconfig.json --config nest-cli.json
```

[Barrelsby](https://www.npmjs.com/package/barrelsby) is for generating index.ts (transpiled in index.js) with all the exports, it could been done better I’m sure but I don’t believe it’s the root cause.

my `nest-cli.json` configurations are the same in my two projects

```json
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "@nestjs/swagger",
        "options": {
          "introspectComments": true,
          "controllerKeyOfComment": "summary"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

as well as the `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "ignoreDeprecations": "5.0", // ignore the "error TS5101"
    "paths": {},
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  }
}
```

Note: it works when I manually add `@ApiProperty()` decorator to the class in the shared package but that’s not my goal.

I believe the problem is somehow related to the transpilation of the shared package, but I’ve played around for quite some times without being able to do it.

I'm not confortable with sharing the whole code from my company but let ne know if you need any details!

Has anyone any clue?
Thanks!